Seeking Assistance with "Run Current File in Interactive Window" Command and Variables Window Issues in Theia with Python/Jupyter Extensions
I have been endeavoring to utilize Theia as a web-based IDE for assisting with Python script development online. To that end, I have installed the following VSCode extensions:
ms-python.python-2024.2.1.vsix
ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.4.2024041702@linux-x64.vsix
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap-1.1.2.vsix
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.17.vsix
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags-0.1.9.vsix
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow-0.1.6.vsix
vscpde.ipynb-1.83.1.vsix
vscode.builtin-notebook-renderers-1.83.1.vsix
vscode.python-1.83.1.vsix

For the most part, these extensions are functioning as expected within Theia. However, I am encountering two specific issues:
Issue 1: When attempting to right-click on a Python file and select "Run Current File in Interactive Window," an error is generated:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Command with id 'interactive.open' is not registered.
    at CommandRegistryMainImpl.$executeCommand (command-registry-main.ts:97:19)
    at ProxyHandler.$proxyHandler (proxy-handler.ts:134:71)
    at async RpcProtocol.handleRequest (rpc-protocol.ts:232:28)

Upon delving into the source code of Theia, its plugins, and VSCode itself, it appears that the 'interactive.open' command is indeed exclusive to VSCode, which might explain the error encountered in Theia.
Issue 2: In Jupyter notebooks panel, the Variables window fails to display any variables while executing an .ipynb script.
Despite extensive searching within this forum, I have been unable to locate any guidance or solutions addressing these particular problems. Consequently, I am seeking clarification on whether these functionalities are currently supported within Theia, or if there are any known workarounds to overcome these issues. Any assistance or insight would be greatly appreciated.
